# Add active class to Bootstrap navbar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**The Problem**

In short.

> a) mysite.tld (nothing happens)
>
> b) mysite.tld/somepage (.active is added)

As you can see b) will have the code add .active class, however the code will ignore if the url is a)

However on the main page I don't want the href be lets say **href="index.html"** or whatever. Instead it's just **href="mysite.tld"**

**The Code**

```
var path = location.pathname.split('?')[0];
var start = path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
var activeLink = path.substr(start);

var parent = $('a[href*="' + activeLink + '"]').parent('li');
// These two lines check if you have dropdowns in your nav-bar

   if (parent.closest('ul').hasClass('dropdown-menu')) {
            parent.parents('.dropdown').addClass('active');
   }

parent.addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the variables to see what is returned after the page loads? If you are using chrome, you can just open the developer console and look at what is logged. Alternatively, instead of `console.log()` you can use `alert()`

```
    var path = location.pathname.split('?')[0];
    var start = path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    var activeLink = path.substr(start);

    consolel.log(path);
    console.log(start);
    console.log(activeLink);

    var parent = $('a[href*="' + activeLink + '"]').parent('li');
    // These two lines check if you have dropdowns in your nav-bar

       if (parent.closest('ul').hasClass('dropdown-menu')) {
                parent.parents('.dropdown').addClass('active');
       }

    parent.addClass('active');
```

Once you are sure the proper variables are being pulled, id recommend narrowing the link down to a tag or class that it might be in, and also using the ends with designation ($) instead of contains(*)

```
 var parent = $('ul li a[href$="' + activeLink + '"]').parent();
```

Might I also suggest debugging by [setting breakpoints using the chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints)

Comment: The script does work, it simply won't add active class to the Home link which is essentially just the website url with no index.html or whatever name in it. If the website pointed to index.html right away then the script will add .active class to it. The problem is with the script not being sure what to do if there is nothing after the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would just be a temporary solution, since `location.href` returns the current URI.

```
if(location.href ==  //example.something) {
    // add active class here
} else {
    // your code here
}
```